# Combining SAP GUI scripts with Microsoft Excel Macros

Tags: excel, sap-gui

I have a sneaking suspicion that this topic has been covered but I have not found an answer that fits, or more to the point, that I understand.  I'm still learning a lot, and as a noob I have a long way to go.

We have a customized report that takes a very long time to run in SAP GUI (2 or more hours).  The recurring problem is that if I do not act on it just as soon as I can after it completes, the whole system times out on me and I lose everything.

My goal is to create something that will run the report, immediately export it into Microsoft Excel (XXL format to remain consistent with historical stuff), and then save it to a specific place on a shared drive.  I would like to be able to set the whole thing running when I leave at night so It will be there the next morning.  I don't care if SAP times out after the fact.

I know how to simply record a script in both SAP and in Excel, but I don't know how to combine them.  A simple copy and paste of the code from SAP into excel generated errors that I don't understand.

I am currently playing with GuiXT, but to be frank, I don't know what I am doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Report running 2 hours IS NOT normal and should be rebuilt. If it's custom one then it is definitely bad architecture, and if standard, then it can be splitted into smaller ones by playing with selection parameters, variants and background jobs.

Comment: I even had systems with idle timeout of 20 min. I have no idea how you can use such huge report at all.

Comment: I wish I could just rebuild the whole thing but I am jsut a lowly user and al of that stuff is handled by a group in another country.  Suffice to say I can't make any alterations to the report itself.  As for the output, a one month run takes roughly 1.5 to 2 hours and returns 5k to 6k lines of output across 104 columns.  I can sometimes it get it to run as much as 3 months worth at a time, but that takes 3 hours or more, and sometimes it just times out in the middle not matter what I try.  I know I am dealing with a bad implementation.  They botched it years ago, I just want to get good info.

Comment: Do you have the option to run the report as a background job (F9) and have the results mailed to you (or grab the spool list via SP01 afterwards)?

Comment: I tried running in background a few days ago, but it seems to only want to dump straight to the printer, which would be useless.  other options are to a pdf or XPS, and neither of those are useful.  After that, I'm not sure which parameters I should choose.  I read one article (I wish I could remember where) that mentioned SE37 and SM38, but I'm not authorized to get to either of those screens. Is there some documentation you could point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to read the following page: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3450067

Particularly interesting for it is from 08.11.2013.

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  It's pretty painfully obvious I need to go back and get some basics under my belt.  I haven't really messed with VB in many years and I'm afraid I don't understand it well enough to tweek your responses into something that works, because I really do not know what I am seeing or how it applies.  I do know that whatever I end up having to do will be a rather ugly work around.  thanks again for your support.